# Serialize and deserialize a list of Sobject for Future method

Tags: apex, json, future, deserialize, serialization

I am trying to pass a list Account records to a future method. Since future can only take primitives, I am planning to serialize and deserialize the Sobject. I tried below:

```
List<Account> acList;// I get a list of account from some other method.
String str = JSON.serialize(acList);


@future
public static void createAccount(String inp){
List<Account> acc = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(inp); // this is not correct. I am trying to figure out a way where I could use something like this. 
insert acc;
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use `@future` here as opposed to using `Queueable`?

Comment: Alternatively, can you instead pass enough data to your future method to generate the list of Accounts you want to insert instead of generating them in the synchronous part of the transaction?

Comment: I have to create a new classes ( with DAO layer to just do an insert) for that. I was wondering if I could do it simple with a small method of 5-6 lines of code if possible

Comment: the logic to generate list of Accounts is not in my control. It's been passed to the class.

Comment: If its gonna be a lot of lines of code, I can probably move it to queueable class and do an insert there.

Comment: `List<Account> acc = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(inp,List<Account>.class);`

Comment: wow that was simple. I tried that incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand the need to throw this out to a separate transaction? In all honesty you should just insert it once you have the info.

That to one side, the answer to how you deserialize.

```
@future
public static void createAccount(String inp){
   List<Account> acc = (List<Account>) JSON.deserialize(inp, List<Account>.class);
   insert acc;
}
```

Comment: The reason was I have a setup and a non setup object in the same transaction. THanks!

Comment: Ah that makes sense, no probs.

Answer (score 5):

Future methods are relatively primitive. Consider using a Queueable instead:

```
List<Account> acList;// I get a list of account from some other method.
System.enqueueJob(new AsyncInsertDml(acList));
```

Where AsyncInsertDml would be:

```
public class AsyncInsertDml implements Queueable {
  sObject[] records;
  public AsyncInsertDml(sObject[] source) {
    records = source;
  }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    insert records;
  }
}
```

This saves the serialization/deserialization step, and System.enqueueJob lets you get an AsyncApexJob Id that you can check for later to verify if it worked or not.

Comment: Relatively primitive. Ha.